# (QGIS) Unable to change shape of polygon

Tags: qgis, polygon, editing, polygon-creation, vertices

I am failing to change the shape of a polygon I just drew. I need to enlarge it by moving one or two vertices somewhere else. I have selected the shape,  toggled edit mode on, selected the Edit Node tool, and all google answers are telling me to just click, hold and and drag the desired vertix. However, the vertex does not follow my cursor when I do so.

I have been working with QGIS for only a week. I have experience with ArcGIS.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In QGIS click on the vertice, then click where you want it to go.  Don't hold and drag.  ArcGIS uses the hold and drag.

Comment: Which version of QGIS are you using? Functionality differs from 3.6 to 3.14.

Comment: It's always a good idea to check the official documenation. For moving vertices, see: https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#vertex-tool (you must scross down a bit). It says: "Select all the vertices you want to move, click on a selected vertex or edge, and click on the desired new location".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usage of the vertex tool has changed from previous versions, so the click-drag-release way does not work anymore. The new mode is click on vertex - click on target position.

In general, new users have to keep in mind that the fast development within QGIS is not always reflected in the ever growing amount of outdated internet resources.